# Menu controls like Office 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, menu, ribbon, office-2010

Hi
Is there a way(tool) to my WinApp written in C# using Visual Studio 2010 have menu controls which look like on these We can fund in Office 2010?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As in, "how do I add a Ribbon to my WinForms app?" Last I checked, Office 2010 is pretty light on the whole "menu" thing.

Comment: @DOK: Given how often the word "menu" appears in this question, doesn't it seem a little premature to add the tag "ribbon"? I had the same thought as you, but that's why I asked. Adding the tag makes it look like it was included by the asker.

Comment: @Cody Gray: If the questioner had known that this was called a ribbon, they would probably have included that word in the question (or better yet, the title). And, they could probably have found the answer quite easily using Google. I often add tags to questions so that future searchers will be more easily led to existing answers to their questions. For example, right now there are over 1200 questions tagged with "menu" but only 240 tagged with "ribbon". I often try to help new users -- I don't expect a person with  one point (as the questioner is right now) to understand the nuances of tags.

Comment: @DOK: My point is that they're different things. It seems like you're taking a lot of liberty here to assume that's what they meant. There *are* traditional menus in Office 2010 that you can enable if you so choose, and some Office applications do not yet use the Ribbon. It's no different than assuming someone means C++ when they ask a question about C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for is called a "**ribbon**", and yes, you can accomplish that on a Winforms application.

[Here is one detailed example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/windowsribbon01.aspx) of how to do it for free. (That article doesn't seem to have links for its five parts; just change the "01" to "02", '03" and so on to walk through it.)

There is also a free [CodePlex project](http://windowsribbon.codeplex.com/) that generates a Windows ribbon.

Comment: Hi Tks a lot I ll have a look in this CodePlex Project, looks interesting and I think it is exactlly what I am looking for.

Comment: I found microsoft wpf toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're considering buying a component take a look at :
http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms.aspx#Overview

Comment: thank you asha for your reply, but I am looking for something opensource that I can use it.

Comment: I found microsoft wpf toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

In `Visual Studio 2012` its added by default
but if you use `Visual Studio 2010` check [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877)

Comment: Try adding the details to the answer and not just a link. SO answers should be free standing.